# ResourceBundle.getBundle returning actual object in spite of mockStatic and when() directing otherwise

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock, resourcebundle, mockstatic

I'm creating tests over existing classes. A number of them have a resource bundle defined as a private final field that's initialized when the object is created via new. I declare a mocked ResourceBundle, use PowerMock's mockStatic method to enable static mocking, and mock the getBundle method to return my mocked ResourceBundle. However, when the constructor runs the code to initialize the field, it simply creates the new resource bundle rather than using the mocked one. I feel like there's one little detail I've missed, but I don't know what it might be.
The reason all this is a problem is this: when I run the test locally, it creates the ResourceBundle object without issue. But when the test is run via our build software (UCBuild), it throws a "can't find resource" exception and the test, and therefore the build, fails.

When I run a test in debug and set a method breakpoint on the constructor, I can see that the "strings" object is created using an actual resource bundle, not the mocked one. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I've tried declaring the field without initializing it, then using class.getDeclaredField() and Field.setAccesible() to set the resource bundle to point at my mocked one, but of course this just gets overwritten if I run code that re-initializes the field.

The WorkerTest class which tests Worker.java:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FacesContext.class, SaveStatus.class, FacesMessage.class, ResourceBundle.class})
public class WorkerTest {
@Mock
    private ResourceBundle mockRB;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ResourceBundle.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ResourceBundle.getBundle(anyString())).thenReturn(mockRB);
        PowerMockito.when(mockRB.getString(anyString())).thenReturn("tst");

        sut = new Worker();  // Breakpoint here to verify mockRB exists
    }
...some tests
}
```

Worker.java:

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Worker implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4075799125164038417L;
    private final ResourceBundle strings = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle("com.resources.strings");

    public Worker() {  //method breakpoint here

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Adding `Worker.class` to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation line and everything worked fine.